# How to add custom buttons to window titlebar in X window

Tags: button, x11, titlebar

I use ubuntu with LXDE and I wonder if I could add some extra buttons to the standard set of minimize, maximize, close. Is it possible? Shall I dig in X11 sources or of smth else?

Answer (score 1):

X11 does not know anything about window manager. Most probably your question is WM-specific, but you can try to look at [ICCCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-Client_Communication_Conventions_Manual) for generic solution

Answer (score 1):

Window titlebars, borders, and other decorations are created by the window manager in X11, not the X server or libraries, so you'd need to look at the LXDE window manager sources for that.